# I want to position top UIView on top of UITableView using SnapKit

Tags: swift, uitableview, snapkit

I'm written in snapkit for UI render. I have not use storyboard or nib files.

I want to position top UIView on top of UITableView using SnapKit.

How to write it?

Below is my written code

```
swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var data: [String] = []
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var subView = UIView()
    var label = UILabel()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        label.text = "Hello?"
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.subView)
        self.subView.addSubview(self.label)
        self.subView.backgroundColor = .gray

        self.tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()

        }
        self.subView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.width.equalTo(self.tableView)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.tableView)
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        self.label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.centerY.equalTo(self.subView)
        }
        for i in 0...100 {
            data.append("\(i)")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let element = self.data[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comicListCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .normal, reuseIdentifier: "comicListCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = element
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(self.data[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

My code :
[image]

I want it!:
[image]
[image]

UIView must placed into UITableView children !!

Sorry my bad english..

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why dont you set the view as the TableHeaderView?. would be much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily add the tableView method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if section == 0 {
        return self.subView
    } else {
        return UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! It's working on my project :)

Comment: I’m glad I helped!

Comment: If tableview has more than one section. Each section has this subview.

Comment: Hmm.. What should I do..?

Comment: @YUKIYUKI I believe Emre-Özdil is right. Changing it to the edited post will still work and will give the correct output in case you add sections.

Comment: It's working too. but now i used Emre-Özdil's code! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You want subview which is sticky header of tableview. Change this line `self.tableView.addSubview(self.subView)` to 
`tableView.tableHeaderView = subView`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I changed original code to tableView.tableHeaderView = subView. then, first scroll page is crashed.. a little scrolling is what i want. Can you tell me why?

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: viewForHeaderInSection delegate is not a proper solution.